# Using a TPL Task to update the UI does not immediately update the UI

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have a .NET Windows Form that creates a task to run asynchronously. That task should call to update the UI of it's progress. It works, but the progress bar only gets updated with some kind of delay.

```
public partial class WaitDialog : Form
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    private void ReportViewerWaitForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Calculate(), _cancellationTokenSource.Token);   
        _asyncTask.ContinueWith(task => Close(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
    }

    private void Calculate()
    {
        UpdateProgressCount(0, 1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            // do some heavy work here
            UpdateProgressCount(i);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUserInterface(Action action)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler).Wait();
    }

    public void UpdateProgressCount(int count)
    {
        UpdateUserInterface(() => progressBar.Value = count);
    }

    public void UpdateProgressCount(int count, int total)
    {
        UpdateUserInterface(() =>
            {
                progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar.Maximum = total;
            });
        UpdateProgressCount(count);
    }

    private void WaitForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_asyncTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The progress bar is being set correctly, by the time the form closes it's value is set to 1000 (or 100%) but it is not displayed this way on the UI, it only ever shows about 50% completion.

The Task to update the UI is started and then Wait() is called, but the asynchronous task seems to keep running before the UI is updated. I assume this is because the UI thread itself did some sort of BeginInvoke() to update the UI.

Ultimately, by the time the asynchronous (heavy work) task finishes, the UI is not updated completely and the form closes. But the UI task Wait(), Application.DoEvents() or progressBar.Update() have any effect to allow the UI to update before returning to the heavy-work task.

Answer (score 1):

In UpdateProgressCount, you might want to instead invoke your form with the progress. That is the standard way of updating things, not by creating another task.

Additionally, I believe that by waiting on a task that is running on the UI thread, your background threads will continue to run. But I may be incorrect about that part. Anyway, if you invoke your form with the progress that should fix your issue.

Comment: So.. replace the task in UpdateUserInterface() with simply Invoke(action) -> doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that your progress bar is set to 1000 maximum value?

Comment: Yep, by the time the FormClosing event fires it's definitely at 1000. The UI is just not updating as soon as the UI task finishes. If I add a Thread.Sleep(50) after the UI task Wait(), the progress bar reaches up to 75%. If I change that to Thread.Sleep(100), the progress bar gets up to 95%. Also, if I remove the Close() call from the async task continuation naturally the UI finishes updating and the progress gets to 100%.

Comment: There should be no Wait() anywhere. if you replace updateuserinterface with an invoke, it should work.

Comment: @user981225 Invoke should work, but so should the OPs solution. I'm curious to see what the bug is.

Comment: It doesn't. I think it is because the form closes before all the UI messages get pumped (due to the async task continuation in the Form_Load method). If the progressBar gets set to 50, there seems to be no way to wait for the UI to actually _display_ that value in the progress bar before continuing on with the async task.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create another task for UI updating, calling the invoke method to update the state in WinForm `progressBar`.

Replace the

```
UpdateUserInterface(() => progressBar.Value = count)
```

To

```
if (progressBar.InvokeRequired) {
    progressBar.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = count);
} else {
    progressBar.Value = count;
}
```